# What is the meaning of the name "Fahrenheit" (or its etymology)?

Tags: meaning, etymology, person-names

What is the definition of the noun "Fahrenheit" (or the etymology of the name)? In Wiktionary it says "[the surname literally means "experience](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Fahrenheit)", but I don't find any evidence of this in the Wahrig or Duden (online) dictionaries.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast The linked question does not ask explicitly for the etymology of the name, and in fact, the answers given there don't say anything about the current question beyond speculation.

Comment: @PerlDuck, the OP obviously knows that it is a name and asks for its meaning or origin.

Comment: @PerlDuck, I looked at the edit history before replying.

Comment: Not an answer, but the first comment in the other question:  "Erfahrenheit" is an old German word for "Erfahrung" (experience) that is not used any more. It is not related to Fahrenheit. – Takkat♦ Dec 15 '11 at 7:27